# About fractal structures

Tags: geometry, fractals

I read somewhere that we can not measure the length of the Adriatic Coast because it has fractal structure. I want some concrete explanation for the fractal structure

Comment: Seen [this](http://users.math.yale.edu/~bbm3/web_pdfs/howLongIsTheCoastOfBritain.pdf)?

Comment: You might get something out of Andre's answer to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41098/distance-to-cross-a-city-diagonally

Comment: Read [The Fractal Geometry of Nature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fractal_Geometry_of_Nature) by Benoît Mandelbrot.

Answer (score 1):

Adriatic Coast cannot be a perfect fractal: It's kind of a fractal-like structure. You can read about fractals [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal). Simply, fractals are self-similar infinitely repeating structures.